# Помогите написать алгоритм поиска среднеарифметического отрицательных чисел в каждой строке массива

Tags: c++

Вот код:

```
const unsigned int DIM1 = 5;
const unsigned int DIM2 = 7;
int i, sum, sred;

float ary[DIM1][DIM2];

for (int i = 0; i < DIM1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < DIM2; j++) {
        ary[i][j] = rand() % 109 + (-37);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < DIM1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < DIM2; j++) {
        cout << setw(4) << ary[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Что делает этот код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const unsigned int DIM1 = 5;
const unsigned int DIM2 = 7;

float ary[DIM1][DIM2];

for (int i = 0; i < DIM1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < DIM2; j++) {
        ary[i][j] = rand() % 109 + (-37);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < DIM1; i++) {
    int count = 0; double sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < DIM2; j++) {
        cout << setw(4) << ary[i][j];
        if (ary[i][j] < 0) { count++; sum += ary[i][j]; };
    }
    if (count == 0) cout << "   No negatives";
    else cout << "   Average negatives is " << sum/count;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: СПАСИБО ! ВСЕ РАБОТАЕТ !

Answer (score -1):

```
float sa[DIM1];
for (int i = 0; i < DIM1; i++)
{
    int index = 0;
    sa[i] = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < DIM2; j++)
    {
        if (ary[i][j] < 0) {
            sa[i] += ary[i][j];
            index++;
        }

    }
    if(index !=0)
    sa[i] /= index;
    cout << "Sa[" << i << "] = " << sa[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Что это? Как этим пользоваться?

Comment: sa - это массив среднеарифметического строки
index -  количество отрицательных  чисел в строке

Comment: а как пользоваться вставляешь в программу после вывода основного массива